# Char Type based template for string_view

Tags: c++, c++17

I'm trying to create a functions that Compares a string or a char array to either a char array or an other string, and I want it to handle utf8 and ascii format.

Here's the beta version of the code:

```
bool equals (const std::string& To, const std::string& What)
{
    return ! To.compare (0, What.length (), What);
}
```

This may create one or 2 strings at runtime and that could have additional cost. And it only handles ascii strings.
I'm trying to turn it to :

```
template <typename CharT>
bool equals (const std::basic_string_view<CharT> To, const 
std::basic_string_view<CharT> What)
{
    return ! To.compare (0, What.length (), What);
}
```

This does compile with gcc8, atleast in the case that the first argument is an std::string and the second argument is a const char*. Since basic_string_view is not parent of basic_string.

```
./test.cpp:14:28: error: no matching function for call to 'equals(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>&, const char [6])'
if (equals (prop, "Prop="))
                        ^
./test.cpp:5:6: note: candidate: 'template<class T, class C> bool equals(std::basic_string_view<C>, std::basic_string_view<C>)'
bool equals (const std::basic_string_view<C> iTo, const std::basic_string_view<C> iWhat)
  ^~~~~~
./test.cpp:5:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
./test.cpp:14:28: note:   'std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>' is not derived from 'std::basic_string_view<C>'
if (equals (prop, "Prop="))
```

So I need to say to the template what CharT is?
Is there a way to do that?

Comment: What's wrong with `==`? Note that your `equals()` doesn't actually check that `To` and `What` have the same contents... it checks that `What` is a prefix of `To`.

Comment: "*So I need to say to the template what CharT is? Is there a way to do that?*" - the compiler will be able to deduce that for you at the call site: `equals(someString.c_str(), someArray);` where `CharT` is deduced as `char` based on the parameters passed in. But, if you want to be explicit about what `CharT` is, you can do that, too: `equals<char>(someString.c_str(), someArray);`

Comment: @Barry : I agree that equals is not really the good name, but names are hard.

the idea is to call
    auto somePropertyWithValue = "PropertyA=1234"s;
    if (equals (somePropertyWithValue, "PropertyA")
   ... (getting 1234 out of the string)

So it is wanted here to only match the length of the What.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I'm trying to avoid to manual cast the string to a char array. string has a operator to convert it to the proper string_view. Trying to implicitly use that.

Comment: @LayfonWeller "*string has a operator to convert it to the proper string_view*" - I was looking for one but couldn't find it, that is why I mentioned `c_str`. But even with the implicit conversion, that doesn't change what I said about deducting the template parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want a template. I think you just want:

```
bool starts_with(std::string_view str, std::string_view prefix);
```

The problem with templates is that templates deduce - that is what they do. But you don't want to *deduce*, you really do want to convert. You want to convert `string` or `char const*` or whatever to `string_view`. So no templates, just conversion.

---

Note that in C++20, this member function will exist:

```
bool starts_with(std::string_view str, std::string_view prefix) {
    return str.starts_with(prefix);
}
```

Until then:

```
bool starts_with(std::string_view str, std::string_view prefix) {
    return str.size() >= prefix.size() && str.compare(0, prefix.size(), prefix) == 0;
}
```

Comment: The idea is to have it accept other formats of strings like utf8 and ascii. That is the reason I'm trying to use template. It seems odd that I need to basically copy paste to support utf8 and other strings. Guess I can use the macros, do create the alternates to that I don't have a case of having to fix it/update multiple time...